# double buffer for consumer and producer problem

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, c++14

So I am trying to implement a double buffer for a typical producer and consumer problem.

1.get_items() basically produces 10 items at a time.

2.producer basically push 10 items onto a write queue. Assume that currently we only have one producer.

3.consumers will consume one item from the queue. There are many consumers.

So I am sharing my code as the following. The implementation idea is simple, consume from the readq until it is empty and then swap the queue pointer, which the readq would point to the writeq now and writeq would now points to the emptied queue and would starts to fill it again. So producer and consumer can work independently without halting each other. This sort of swaps space for time.

However, my code does not work in multiple consumer cases. In my code, I initiated 10 consumer threads, and it always stuck at the .join().

So I am thinking that my code is definitely buggy. However, by examine carefully, I did not find where that bug is. And it seems the code stuck after lk1.unlock(), so it is not stuck in a while or something obvious.

```
mutex m1;
mutex m2; // using 2 mutex, so when producer is locked, consumer can still run


condition_variable put;
condition_variable fetch;

queue<int> q1;
queue<int> q2;

queue<int>* readq = &q1;
queue<int>* writeq = &q2;

bool flag{ true };
vector<int> get_items() {
    vector<int> res;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        res.push_back(i);
    }
    return res;
}

void producer_mul() {
    unique_lock<mutex> lk2(m2);
    put.wait(lk2, [&]() {return flag == false; }); //producer waits for consumer signal
    vector<int> items = get_items();
    for (auto it : items) {
        writeq->push(it);
    }
    flag = true; //signal queue is filled
    fetch.notify_one();
    lk2.unlock();
}


int get_one_item_mul() {
    unique_lock<mutex> lk1(m1);
    int res;
    if (!(*readq).empty()) {   
        res = (*readq).front(); (*readq).pop();  
        if ((*writeq).empty() && flag == true) { //if writeq is empty
            flag = false;
            put.notify_one();
        }
    }
    else {
        readq = writeq; // swap queue pointer
        while ((*readq).empty()) { // not yet write
            if (flag) {
                flag = false;  
                put.notify_one();//start filling process
            }
            //if (readq->empty()) {       //upadted due to race. readq now points to writeq, so if producer finished, readq is not empty and flag = true.
                fetch.wait(lk1, [&]() {return flag == true; }); 
            //}
        }
        if (flag) {
            writeq = writeq == &q1 ? &q2 : &q1; //swap the writeq to the alternative queue and fill it again
            flag = false;
            //put.notify_one(); //fill that queue again if needed. but in my case, 10 item is produced and consumed, so no need to use the 2nd round, plus the code does not working in this simple case..so commented out for now.
        }
        res = readq->front(); readq->pop();
    }
    lk1.unlock();
    this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
    return res;
}



int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::packaged_task<void(void)> job1(producer_mul);
    vector<std::future<int>> res;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::packaged_task<int(void)> job2(get_one_item_mul);
        res.push_back(job2.get_future());
        threads.push_back(std::thread(std::move(job2)));
    }

    threads.push_back(std::thread(std::move(job1)));

    for (auto& t : threads) {
        t.join();
    }

    for (auto& a : res) {
        cout << a.get() << endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

I added some comments, but the idea and code is pretty simple and self-explanatory.

I am trying to figure out where the problem is in my code. Does it work for multiple consumer? Further more, if there are multiple producers here, does it work? I do not see a problem since basically in the code the lock is not fine grained. Producer and Consumer both are locked from the beginning till the end.

Looking forward to discussion and any help is appreciated.

**Update**

updated the race condition based on one of the answer.
The program is still not working.

Comment: And what result did the debugger yield?

Comment: It looks like the producer and consumer are accessing the same queue concurrently. Initially `readq` is empty so we enter the else branch in `get_one_item_mul()` and make `readq` point to the same queue as `writeq`. After calling `put.notify_one()` the producer will start filling the queue, so the call to `readq->empty()` can return false and thereby skipping the wait until the producer has finished modifying the queue. The consumer can then call `readq->pop()` while the producer is pushing items into the queue.

Comment: Off the top, you have a data race on `flag`. `producer_mul` reads and modifies it under `m2`, while `get_one_item_mul` does the same under `m1`. Which effectively means it's not protected from concurrent access at all.

Comment: Why are you doing `fetch.notify_one()` and not `notfiy_all`, when a) you have multiple consumers, and b) you generate multiple items for them to consume?

Comment: You have a similar data race on `writeq` (not on the queue it points to, but on the pointer itself). `producer_mul` reads it under `m2`, while `get_one_item_mul` modifies it under `m1`.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 there is no result yield. This program is runnable, from my side, the debugging stops after first woke up consumer thread released its lock, then the program seems to be in a endless loop, and would never print anything nor stop.

Comment: @IanGralinski updated, but still not working. There are other hidden issues... which are not so obvious i guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program contains data races, and therefore exhibits undefined behavior. I see at least two:

- `producer_mul` accesses and modifies `flag` while holding `m2` mutex but not `m1`. `get_one_item_mul` accesses and modifies `flag` while holding `m1` mutex but not `m2`. So `flag` is not in fact protected against concurrent access.
- Similarly, `producer_mul` accesses `writeq` pointer while holding `m2` mutex but not `m1`. `get_one_item_mul` modifies `writeq` while holding `m1` mutex but not `m2`.

---

There's also a data race on the queues themselves. Initially, both queues are empty. `producer_mul` is blocked waiting on `flag`. Then the following sequence occurs ( `P` for producer thread, `C` for consumer thread):

```
C: readq = writeq;  // Both now point to the same queue
C: flag = false; put.notify_one();  // This wakes up producer
  **P: writeq->push(it);
  **C: if (readq->empty())
```

The last two lines happen concurrently, with no protection against concurrent access. One thread modifies an `std::queue` instance while the other accesses that same instance. This is a data race.

---

There's a data race at the heart of the design. Let's imagine there's just one producer `P` and two consumers `C1` and `C2`. Initially, `P` waits on `put` until `flag == false`. `C1` grabs `m1`; `C2` is blocked on `m1`.

`C1` sets `readq = writeq`, then unblocks `P1`, then calls `fetch.wait(lk1, [&]() {return flag == true; });`. **This unlocks `m1`**, allowing `C2` to proceed. So now `P` is busy writing to `writeq` while `C2` is busy reading from `readq` - which is one and the same queue.

Comment: i should disagree first with the flag race. It is obvious to first think that the flag is race condition. However, when there is one producer, and the producer actually waits on the consumer, there should not be a race condition. 1. consider consumer starts first, one consumer runs to empty condition, notify producer, while producer is not yet start, then fetch goes back to wait the producer, and the rest consumer should stop at the acquiring lock step. 2. producer starts first, then it stops at wait. Consumer would first change the flag and then notify producer.

Comment: If you are actually thinking the flag would have a race condition, could you describe what that condition is specially. At what step would the producer and consumer fight to change the flag at the same time. I could not think of any yet.

Comment: The scope is limited to 1 producer produces 10 item, 10 consumer each consumes just 1 item. So the put.notify() would not be called again after its first call.

Comment: Even without going to the logic of the program - a condition variable is allowed to wake up spuriously. So `put.wait` could wake up without being notified, lock `m2` and check `flag` - at the precise moment that the consumer sets `flag` under `m1`.

Comment: There's a more obvious data race caused by a clear logic error. I added it to the answer.

Comment: apologize for saying that i am more confused regarding the flag race by your follow up. put.wait can wake up spuriously, but it wakes up and check the flag rather than set. And it finds out flag == true, it falls back to sleep. If it finds that flag == false, it continue and set flag to true, and by that point,consumer already unlocked, which cause another waiting consumer grabs the lock, and waits for the flag to be true. So there is no race in my current problem scope, no matter producer starts first or consumer starts first. There maybe race if there are multiple consumer and producer.

Comment: And thanks for pointing out the other race of accessing the same queue at the same time. I do not have the check empty() there before, but the code seems to be in a deadlock situation, so i added that line. I delete it now, but the code still does not work.

Comment: It's a data race to read a memory location in one thread concurrently with writing it in another thread. You are thinking of `flag` as an atomic variable - but it's not in fact `std::atomic`

Comment: `flag = false; put.notify_one(); fetch.wait(lk1, [&]() {return flag == true; });` is a data race on `flag`. After `put.notify_one()`, the producer thread would wake up and modify `flag`; while the consumer thread would check `flag` before going to sleep, possibly concurrently with that modification.

Comment: Updated the answer the third time. There's a data race at the heart of the design, that doesn't rely on such subtleties as spurious wakes and non-atomic access. It's straight up reading and writing the same queue at the same time from two threads with no synchronization.

Comment: @lgor thanks again for responding to my question. This is more than writing to a queue and read from it at the same time. It is trickier than that. A queue can be read and written at the same time without conflict, if the queue implementation is linkedlist, which is a unbounded queue. The code basically does not work on multiple consumer cases, and the problem is the fetch would release the lock to other consumers, which will cause problem. The other consumer then can wait again, or swap the queue again before C1 consumes anything, and also compete for resources.producer only notify once, see.

Comment: C2 if falls into sleep, would never wake up again since P1 also only called once.Problem solved. Thanks for leading me to the right solution. Though you answer is close.You point me to think that exact line that causes problem. This code would work for 1 consumer 1 producer case.

Comment: Most standard library classes, and `std::queue` in particular, are not thread-safe. The standard places requirements on a program not to modify (call non-const methods on) `std::queue` instance on one thread while another thread reads or modifies the same instance. A program that does so, exhibits undefined behavior. Internal implementation details of `std::queue` are irrelevant. Yes, it is possible in principle to implement a thread-safe queue, but `std::queue` ain't that. Believing otherwise is wishful thinking.

Comment: I bet you are right about the standard library. Thanks again!